# Replace values in records based on the maximum

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>   ID           value     
>  0001            0                        
>  0001            4                        
>  0001            4                        
>  0002            2                        
>  0002            0                        
>  0002            2                        
>  0002            0                        
> .......       .......
> ```

for each ID I would like to replace the values in  value column with the max to have the following:

> ```
>   ID           value     
>  0001            4                        
>  0001            4                        
>  0001            4                        
>  0002            2                        
>  0002            2                        
>  0002            2                        
>  0002            2                        
> .......       .......
> ```

I tried:

> ```
>     create table wants as  
>       select ID
>           (select max(value)
>           from have
>           where a.ID=ID
>           group by ID) as value
>      from have as a;
>     quit;
> ```

I got this piece of code from another post and although it is ok and works perfectly it takes a lot of times (I have 698.876 rows). Is there a quick way to do the same?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your sample data has a last line ID=1. Should it be 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SAS support analytic functions, then the following should work:

```sql
SELECT ID, MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS value
FROM have
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work so hard with PROC SQL code.  SAS will automatically do the re-merge of the summary statistics for you.

```
create table want as  
  select ID
       , max(value) as value
  from have
  group by id
;
```

The only thing that might take a long time is getting the data grouped (sorted basically) by ID.

If the data is already sorted then you might get better performance writing your own data step.

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    max=max(max,value);
  end;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    value=max;
    output;
  end;
  keep id value;
run;
```